# Prevent Windows from copying pictures to my Android device

Tags: windows-7, android, photos

I had some pictures, a backup from a relatives computer, in my Pictures library / folder. Now it appears that they have been copied on my phone.

Where can this behavior be changed ? I'd like to have a one way synchronization from the Android device to my PC. I can't find which program is responsible for this.

Comment: Sounds like this is done by "Google Backup and Sync" Software on your PC. Check your settings there.

Comment: Do you have a NAS with Google Sync that uploads the pictures?
Don't know what else could cause this.

Comment: Actually I just found that Windows Media Player is responsible for this. I'm still trying to understand how to tweak this, because the discoverability of this is really...low

Comment: So esentially you want to disable auto syncing upon device connection or what?